# Designing AND gate using transistors

Tags: transistors

I am asked to design AND gate using transistors on Multisim simulator

AND Logic Gate: Design and implement AND Logic Gate, which gives high output voltage if and only if its two inputs are at a high voltage level.

should be implemented using BJT transistors.

High voltage level: 3-5 Volts

Low voltage level: 0-0.7 Volts

Vcc= 5V

I should analyse the circuit and get all the resistors value. Can someone help me doing it please ?

Comment: Can you show us how far you have gotten and where you are stuck?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a homework problem with no effort shown.

Comment: Menaeng, See [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/281320/38098). I'm sure you can make the added modifications to meet with the problem requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a AND gate implemented with a BJT transistor. But I’m pretty sure this is not what you’re supposed to do.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2f5h8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Since your question looks much like homework, you should consider (and tell us) what you were taught recently.
You should also tell us what you tried and how far you went.