# One BJT NOR gate resistor values

Tags: bjt, logic-gates

What is the purpose of this RD resistor and how do I calculate all the values in this one bjt NOR circuit to have something reliable. And how do I measure fanout of this gate?

[image: nor]

Comment: Do the A and B inputs work with 0 and 5 V or they use a lower voltage?

Comment: A and B should be possible to be connected on an output of another gate.

Comment: @wolflu The fanout is six loads using a 5 V supply rail. See [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/281320/330261).

Comment: Yes, thank you very much.